# Does Chromium vulnerability also affect CEFSharp Project?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, penetration-testing

new to CEFSharp here. Recently I was assigned a penetration test on a host and I found a CEFSharp project embbed in third party developed software. After some google digging, I was able to find the chromium version 85.x.x and it's pretty dawn old comparing to the latest release.

I'm not sure the vulnerability exist now or later in chromium would become an artifact of compromise on the host through the CEFSharp project, thus, I'm looking for some advise! Thank you for reading.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. Like with most things in life and the universe, it depends... If there is a vulnerability in Chromium that is of concern to you, and you don't have any evidence on the CEF version(s) of interest not being affected by that vulnerability, just ignore it. Party on!... ... Sorry, i meant to say, it would not be a bad idea to be conservative and assume the vulnerability affects CEF as well unless you have evidence or confirmation from an _authoritative_ and _trustworthy_ source that CEF is not affected by that vulnerability.

Comment: Are you asking if any vulnerability in Chromium would lead to a vulnerability in any host application using CEFSharp? If so, no. It depends on the vulnerability and how the host is using CEFSharp. This question does, however, fit better on [security.se].

Answer (score 0):

Firstly CefSharp via the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/README.md) (CEF) allows you to embed Chromium in a .Net application.

CEF historically implements the [Chromium Content API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/content/public/README.md). If the vulnerability exists within the Chromium Content API then the same exploit would most likely work in a CefSharp browser at the same version. CEF only implements a subset of Chromium features.

It's important to consider application usage when determining risk level, if the application in question only ever makes requests to a secure intranet site then the risk of a vulnerability being exploited would typically be very low. It's possible that an application uses only embedded resources and never makes a network request, again very low risk.

You'll need to contact the applications vendor or perform your own risk assessment to determine if using an old version actually poses a problem.